# PHP search script for a product website

Tags: php, search, mysqli

May be this question is localized or "opinion oriented", but I found no forum to ask this question for a better and suitable answers. I have a small products website running in a shared server. And I need a search script for it. But `LIKE` or `LIKE%%` or `REGEXP` results are not that much good and appropriate like most products websites. I cannot install Sphinx since that is for VPS or DEDICATED servers. Is there any PHP-MySQLi search plugin available as free? Or if creating a PHP-MySQLi search engine on own is really possible and worthy, how can I start?

I have tried using `LIKE QUERY` `LIKE %QUERY%` and REGEXP but when user search with more than one word, the results are not as expected. And I used prepared statements which increased the complexity a lot. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is precisely the type of question which is closed on this site.  What made you think asking it here would be a good idea?

Comment: You've tried some programming to solve the problem which is great, but have you tried any Googling? eg: [Apache solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: @MLeFevre: Yeah but, Can Apache Solr be used in a shared hosting?

Comment: @CroResistor It can be, yep.

Answer (score 1):

few ideas:

1. mysql full text search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html http://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/
2. about more than 1 word, you can split the string by space and search by each word separately.